# Choco solver logging

Tags: choco

I'm trying the Choco solver (version 4.10.1) for the first time, and I don't know how to enable logging for the solver. 
I've added slf4j-log4j12 dependency and a log4j.properties file.

For older Choco (e.g. v3) versions, the doc mentioned some stuff about this. for example some `Chatterbox` class, that is no longer present.

Any ideas how to enable some logging for the solver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys from Chocoteam helped. The methods are

```
solver.showXXX()
```

E.g. `showDecisions()`, `showSolutions()`, etc. and also `printStatistics()`

See [javadoc](http://www.choco-solver.org/apidocs/org/chocosolver/solver/trace/IOutputFactory.html) for more information.